# why function called more than once onclick event?

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<ul><li onClick="myFunction(this.id)" id="root">Root</li></ul>

<script>
function myFunction(myid) //id of clicked li 
{

    var id=prompt("Enter Folder id");
    if (id != '' && id != null)
    {
        var val=prompt("Enter Folder name");
    }

    if (id != '' && id != null && val !='' && val !=null) 
    {

        var ulnode=document.createElement("UL"); //new ul
        var node=document.createElement("LI"); //new li
            node.setAttribute("id",id);//set id of new li 
            node.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction(this.id)");//set onclick event of new li 
        var textnode=document.createTextNode(val);//li value
        node.appendChild(textnode);// new li + li value
        ulnode.appendChild(node);// new li + li value

        document.getElementById(myid).appendChild(ulnode);//old+new
    }

}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: 1) Please format your code. 2) Please provide some explanation as to what the problem actually is, and your attempts to fix it.

Comment: Would you mind formatting this a little to make it easier to read?

Comment: just dumping some code into the post with a subject is not how it works around here...provide details of your problem

Comment: sir, i want to create menu like this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/navigate1.htm  but in this menu item should be created dynamically by user input (javascript or jquery only)...help me sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've added a child element, you have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li onClick="myFunction(this.id)" id="root">
        Root
        <ul>
            <li onClick="myFunction(this.id)" id="abc">
                Abc
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since `abc` is a child of `root`, clicking `abc` *also* clicks `root`.  Sometimes you *want* this behavior, but not in your case.  You can stop events from "propagating" to parent elements by calling the `.stopPropagation()` method on the event object.  The event object is passed to event handlers as an argument.

When you bind event handlers using HTML attributes, the attribute value becomes the handler function body, and the event argument is named `event`.  You can either call `event.stopPropagation()` in the event handler, or pass the event object to `myFunction()`.  Personally, I'd make `myFunction()` the handler itself (instead of just a function called by the handler).  Change the function to accept an event object for it's argument.  When you create the child `<li>`, rather than setting the `onclick` attribute, set the `onclick` property and assign it a reference to `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();

    var id=prompt("Enter Folder id");
    if (id != '' && id != null)
    {
        var val=prompt("Enter Folder name");
    }
    if (id != '' && id != null && val !='' && val !=null) 
    {
        var ulnode=document.createElement("UL"); //new ul
        var node=document.createElement("LI"); //new li
        node.id = id;//set id of new li 
        node.onclick = myFunction;//set onclick event of new li 

        var textnode=document.createTextNode(val);//li value
        node.appendChild(textnode);// new li + li value
        ulnode.appendChild(node);// new li + li value

        this.appendChild(ulnode);
    }
}
```

That works for dynamically created list elements.  To bind that function to your root element in the HTML, use `myFunction.call(this, event)`:

```
<ul><li onClick="myFunction.call(this, event)" id="root">Root</li></ul>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzPcw/1/)

---

Note that a benefit of this technique is you have a reference to the `<li>` element in your function, so you don't need to look up the element by id.  If that is the only reason you were adding an id to each list item, you can omit that completely.  The resulting function is quite a bit shorter:

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    var val=prompt("Enter Folder name");
    if (val) 
    {
        var ulnode=document.createElement("UL"); //new ul
        var node=document.createElement("LI"); //new li
        node.onclick = myFunction;//set onclick event of new li 
        node.textContent = val;
        ulnode.appendChild(node);// new li + li value
        this.appendChild(ulnode);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzPcw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are dynamically adding `<li>` elements which might get the same id. If this is the case, this is not allowed. Try to use classes instead and the use of JQuery will be helpful for you. Will shorten the code (at least on your side ;) ) to a minimum.

Use this as a starting point: http://plnkr.co/1apBvS

Also i would separate the button to be in a static place, so you will always see it, even if your `<ul>` is scrolled because it can get many rows.

Comment: Since the ids for the dynamically created list items come from user input, they may or may not be duplicated, depending on user input.  Regardless, duplicate ids would not cause the click handler to be called multiple times per click. This is a good suggestion, but doesn't address the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Events like click bubble up the DOM (propagate) through all parents

Because you are nesting a child that has parent with same click handler, the event first fires `myFunction` on the child, then fires on the parent .

You can return `false` from `myFunction` to prevent the bubbling

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your text inside a `<a></a>`, like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a onclick="return test()">child</a></li>
</ul>
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gongzhitaao/k4UEE/3/

I just tried, but I've no idea why `<li>` with `onclick` does not work.

Comment: @user2985287 By not working, why do you mean? Did you see two popup? I just saw one alert popup.